# Wie sagt man 'a value of a new item'?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

Es gibt ein Buch mit paar leichten Kratzer auf dem Umschlag. Das Buch ist aber im Prinzip neu und ungelesen. Wenn ich über seinem Zustand auf Englisch sagen wollte, würde ich sagen: das Buch hat *a value of a new item*.

Google Translate empfehlt *ein Wert von einem neuen Buch*, aber ich bin sicher, dass man das schöner und kürzer sagen kann.

Comment: I changed "Abdeckung" zu Umschlag (Cover) - and some other things. I hope in your intent.

Comment: Korinthenkackerei abseitig der eigentlichen Frage: Ein Buch mit einem Kratzer auf dem Umschlag ist *nicht* neuwertig. Ein neuwertiges Buch hat keinen Kratzer.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar richtig! So denke ich auch! Ich bin der Meinung, dass _neuwertiges Buch_ und _a used item, which however has a VALUE of a new item_ ganz verschiedene Sachen sind.

Answer (score 12):

In diesem Falle würde man wohl sagen: *Das Buch ist neuwertig* oder *fast neuwertig* (weil es ja ein paar Kratzer hat), oder auch *Das Buch ist fast wie neu*.

Answer (score 3):

Im Gebrauchtwarenmarkt eines bekannten Online-Händlers gibt es einen [Leitfaden für Zustandsangaben](http://www.amazon.de/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_1-1?ie=UTF8&nodeId=3366851&qid=1328383240&sr=1-1%3C/h4%3E), welcher für gebrauchte Bücher die Abstufungen "Wie neu", "Sehr gut", "Gut", "Akzeptabel" und "Inakzeptabel" vorsieht. Basierend darauf wäre es also OK, wenn man sagt: "Das Buch ist wie neu.", insbesondere ohne das "fast" aus Veredomons Antwort. Denn "fast wie neu" wäre dann *nur* noch "sehr gut". Allerdings gefällt mir persönlich das "neuwertig" aus Veredomons Antwort besser als "wie neu", auch wenn letzteres umgangssprachlicher klingt.

Abgesehen davon käme auf besagtem Gebrauchtwarenmarkt ein Buch mit Kratzern auf dem Schutzumschlag nicht mehr für "wie neu" in Frage :)

Comment: Eben. Da laufen viele bibliophile rum, für die ein paar Kratzer schon eine Katastrophe sind. "Value of a new item" würde man so übersetzen, aber ein Buch mit Kratzern dürfte man so nicht anbieten, "Gut",  schätze ich,.wäre die handelsübliche Bezeichnung, am besten mit den konkreten Mängeln, aber ruhig auch dem Pluspunkt "ungelesen".